# iOS Instruments Allocations -- Find Out What/Why Memory was Released

Tags: ios, memory-management, uiimage, sprite-kit, instruments

I have a SpriteKit game where you play a song at a slow tempo and then at a fast tempo. I push a `GameViewController` with a slow tempo. Then after that level is complete, I push a `GameViewController` with a fast tempo. Both of these screens have the same image data (in `SKSpriteNodes`), 60 MB worth of backgrounds essentially. You can see that in the first image:

[image]

When I switch to the fast tempo song, all of my ImageIO_PNG_Data allocations go away! But I can still see the images!

[image]

**Questions**

1. Why/how is this happening?
2. In general, how should I find out why memory is *released* (not allocated)?

Comment: I take it two view controllers means you're creating two separate instances of SKView? If so, avoid doing so. Instead use scene transitions to move between scenes. PS: Sprite Kit has internal caches.

Comment: Ah, I'll try changing to scene transitions. On a related forum post: http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=9203, would you opt for option 1, 2, or 3?

Comment: Also, I don't see a way to access these internal caches. True?